# .netCore3.1 to .net6.0 function app upgrade - Unable to debug in local (DLL error)

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been working on to upgrade my function app `.netcore3.1` solution to `.net6.0`. After upgrading the solution and all the packages - when I run the solution in local - it is throwing below error. I am unable to debug the function app in local. It is throwing error in `startup.cs` class. Any solution for this ?

```cs
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder.get_ConfigurationBuilder()'
```

**.csproj** file

```cs
<PropertyGroup> 
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> 
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion> 
<RootNamespace>Unilever.DigitalFactory_SPC_ControlCharts</RootNamespace> 
<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What is the `Visual Studio` Version you are using?

Comment: Could you please share your `Startup.cs` and `.csproj` file.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022      <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Unilever.DigitalFactory_SPC_ControlCharts</RootNamespace>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Could you please share `Startup.cs` as well.

Comment: In `.csproj` file, Update the `<AzureFunctionsVersion>` v3 to v4 and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `Version="4.1.1"` and check once.

Comment: Yes updating Azure function version worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: But now new issue. Unable to debug the GET method from post man ! 500 - internal server error...Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 'Testfunction' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?. Any idea on this error

Comment: Thansks Harshita ! Latest SDK version 4.1.3 not worked. As you said i updated to 4.1.1. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a Function App with.`NET core 3.1` version.

***My .csproj for .NET Core 3.1***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Migrated from `.net core 3.1` to `.net 6.0`, when I tried with the `.csproj` provided in the code got the below errors.
[image]

In `.csproj` file, Change the `AzureFunctionsVersion` from `v3` to `v4`.
Update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` NuGet Package to latest version - `4.1.1`

***Output:***

[image]

***Code for FunctionsStartup in Startup.cs***

```cs
using Function3Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Function3Core
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

***Code for WebJobsStartup in Startup.cs***

```
using Function3Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Function3Core
{
   class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```